# How to get Common values from JSON array in PHP?

Tags: php, arrays, json

Actually, I trying to get the common values from JSON Array through php

we have 2 arrays

```
$array1 = 
[
    {
        "flower_id": "1",
        "flower_price": "1",
        "flower_name": "Nelumbo"
    },
    {
        "flower_id": "2",
        "flower_price": "2",
        "flower_name": "Water"
    },
    {
        "flower_id": "3",
        "flower_price": "2",
        "flower_name": "Ladys"
    },
    {
        "flower_id": "4",
        "flower_price": "2",
        "flower_name": "Foxtail"
    },
    {
        "flower_id": "5",
        "flower_price": "2",
        "flower_name": "White"
    },
    {
        "flower_id": "6",
        "flower_price": "2",
        "flower_name": "Marigold"
    },
    {
        "flower_id": "7",
        "flower_price": "2",
        "flower_name": "Lotus"
    },
    {
        "flower_id": "8",
        "flower_price": "2",
        "flower_name": "Rhododendron"
    },
    {
        "flower_id": "9",
        "flower_price": "2",
        "flower_name": "Common"
    }]
```

here is the array call $array1
and one more array which is to compare with this array is

```
$array2 =
[
    {
        "flower_id": "1",
        "flower_name": "Nelumbo"
    },
    {
        "flower_id": "3",
        "flower_name": "Ladys Slipper"
    },
    {
        "flower_id": "5",
        "flower_name": "White Orchid-tree"
    },
    {
        "flower_id": "9",
        "flower_name": "Common Rhododendron"
    }
]
```

BUT WE NEED interact with these two arrays and i want result like this

```
[
{
    "flower_id": "1",
    "flower_name": "Nelumbo",
    "flower_price": "1"
},
{
    "flower_id": "3",
    "flower_name": "Ladys Slipper",
    "flower_price": "2"
},
{
    "flower_id": "5",
    "flower_name": "White Orchid-tree",
    "flower_price": "2"
},
{
    "flower_id": "9",
    "flower_name": "Common Rhododendron",
    "flower_price": "2"
}
```

]

How to do get this result from this two arrays?
I have tried this but it shows only common values but i need flower_price to

```
        $new_array = array_diff_key($array1,$array2);
        echo json_encode($supplierArray);
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to find the common items, a quick way is to index both arrays by the `flower_id` (using [`array_column()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-column.php)) and then do an [`array_intersect_key()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-intersect-key.php) which will keep the common items, and as `$array1` is the first array, it will keep all the details from that array.  As this will leave you an array with the key, use [`array_values()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-values.php) to extract just the content ...

```
$a1 = array_column($array1,null,"flower_id");
$a2 = array_column($array2,null,"flower_id");
echo json_encode(array_values(array_intersect_key($a1, $a2)));
```

with your test data it will give...

```
[
    {
        "flower_id": "1",
        "flower_price": "1",
        "flower_name": "Nelumbo"
    },
    {
        "flower_id": "3",
        "flower_price": "2",
        "flower_name": "Ladys"
    },
    {
        "flower_id": "5",
        "flower_price": "2",
        "flower_name": "White"
    },
    {
        "flower_id": "9",
        "flower_price": "2",
        "flower_name": "Common"
    }
]
```

Comment: Thanks bro, It works